# Why does my site redirect to www when I go to example.com but not when I go to https://example.com

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a site that I'm trying to re-direct to www subdomain.

I'm using Namecheap as my URL registar and my DNS.

I've set up this rule

[image]

When I navigate to paperbet.site, it goes to https://www.paperbet.site - which is what I'm after.

However, when I navigate to https://paperbet.site, it does not resolve to www subdomain.

What is the difference between https://url.com and url.com - and why won't the former follow the redirect domain rule?

Answer (score 2):

Namecheap's URL redirection doesn't support HTTPS. Do the redirect yourself in your own web server.